# elastic search scroll limit number of results

Tags: javascript, elasticsearch

Please see code below. What I would like to accomplish is to limit the number per batch size (50) but ALSO limit the number of TOTAL results (1000). Using code sample, I however get ALL matching records as a result. What am I doing wrong? Or isn't this supported at all.

Thanks!

Sander

```
var elasticsearch = require('elasticsearch');
var _ = require('lodash');

var client = new elasticsearch.Client({
    host: 'host',
    log: 'info'
});

var allDocuments = [];
client.search({
    index: "index",
    type: "type",
    scroll: '30s',
    size: 50,
    body: {
        "from": 0,
        "size": 1000,
        "query": {
            "range": {
                "updated": {
                    "gte": "2016-10-24T08:35:10.540Z",
                    "lte": "2016-10-29T20:35:10.541Z"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}, function getMoreUntilDone(error, response) {
    response.hits.hits.forEach(function (hit) {
        allDocuments.push(hit._source);
    });
    if (response.hits.total !== allDocuments.length) {
        client.scroll({
            scrollId: response._scroll_id,
            scroll: '30s'
        }, getMoreUntilDone);
    } else {
        console.log('count', allDocuments.length);
    }
});
```

Comment: Just found this after getting an answer on my similar question, terminateAfter goes outside the body: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45713583/using-elasticsearch-terminate-after-in-query-body-in-javascript/45713729#45713729

Answer (score -2):

Using size will not stop the query after 1000 hits. It will only batch it in the group of 1000. Instead use terminate_after.

```
body: {
            "from": 0,
            "terminateAfter": 1000,
            "query": {
                "range": {
                    "updated": {
                        "gte": "2016-10-24T08:35:10.540Z",
                        "lte": "2016-10-29T20:35:10.541Z"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Tried this. Unfortunately this doesn't work... Maybe because I'm using ES5.0?

Comment: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/api-reference.html

Comment: Please correct the param name to "terminateAfter". I had written "terminate_after" previously.

Comment: Yes, I noticed on the link you send, thanks. But also with terminateAfter it doesn't wok :(. Did you try it yourself?

Comment: BTW, If I add it to the body section I get an error, "reason: 'Unknown key for a VALUE_NUMBER in [terminateAfter]". When I add this to the root of the search object, I don't get an error, but also the result isn't as it should...

Comment: `terminateAfter` works like a crop in the whole index, it won't work as expected with sorted or filtered results because the limit/cropping is applied before running the query, so you may have matching results that will be discarded because of this "cropping" behavior.

Comment: And the right query parameter is `terminate_after` with underscore

Comment: Terminate after gives you that many results per shard, so if you have more than one shard you'll need to use a smaller number.