# Using elasticsearch terminate after in query body in javascript

Tags: javascript, elasticsearch

I am trying to get only one result back for a query I know may return more than one result, so I would like to use the the terminate_after parameter, but I can't work out how to use it in a query body in javascript. I have tried putting it in the body, like below, but I get a `parsing_exception`: `"Unknown key for a VALUE_NUMBER in [terminateAfter]."`

```
client.search({
    index: 'myindex',
    type: 'mytype',
    body: {
        terminateAfter: 1,
        query: {
            term: {
                searchField: searchString
            }
        }
    }
}, function(error, results){}
```

I have also tried putting it inside the query, but this also causes a `parsing_exception`: `"[terminateAfter] query malformed, no start_object after query name"`

I am using version 5.3 of elasticsearch and version 13.3.1 of the elasticsearch npm module.

Comment: It's `terminate_after`, you forgot the underscore_. Your doc is from the Java API, this is the right place to look for the REST API : https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-body.html.

Comment: @MartinSchulze it is correctly written (he uses the JavaScript API), just placed at the wrong location ;-)

Comment: @Val Sorry for the misinformation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've almost got it right, `terminateAfter` should go outside the `body`, like this:

```
client.search({
    index: 'myindex',
    type: 'mytype',
    terminateAfter: 1,
    body: {
        query: {
            term: {
                searchField: searchString
            }
        }
    }
}, function(error, results){}
```

Comment: Thanks, no more errors! I'm still getting 3 hits, but is that because of the shards?

Comment: Yes, as per the documentation, `terminate_after` specifies "the maximum number of documents to collect for each shard, "

Comment: @Carasel did you try to use size: 1 ? You would collect only one result for the whole index instead of 1 per shard